# Is it okey to call collect within a Composable

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, side-effects

I took a look at [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f_iIMscTNjQ) and within it the author explains that making network calls in a composable is a bad habit. But what about getting the results in a `StateFlow` in a composable is that to a bad habit? Or is that okey? So the question is that when you call collect on a `MutableStateFlow` is it okey to do that directly in the compose method and not in the a side effect block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only it is not a bad habit, it is the only way to actually use the result in composable. I wouldn't expose `MutableStateFlow` but rather only `StateFlow`, but the rest is just fine